# Why does printing this variable show a prompt, instead of an error message?

Tags: javascript, prompt, console.log

Please why does `console.log(theMessage)` show a popup prompt, instead of: `"You typed" + textTypedIntoPrompt`.

Or even some error message related to it?

New to programming and just trying to understand why this program works the way that does.

Thanks.

```
var textTypedIntoPrompt = prompt ("Type some text");

var theMessage = "You typed" + textTypedIntoPrompt;

console.log(theMessage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not the [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) which open the popup prompt, it's the [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) function

the log is then done in the console as shown in the snippets below

```js
var textTypedIntoPrompt = prompt("Type some text");
var theMessage = "You typed : " + textTypedIntoPrompt;
console.log(theMessage);
```

here's a detailled explanation of what happens

```
var textTypedIntoPrompt =                              
// create a variable named textTypedIntoPrompt
                          prompt("Type some text");    
// open the popup prompt
// the popup prompt freeze the execution until the prompt was confirmed or dismissed
// once the prompt is confirmed/dismissed the function returns
// either what the user wrote (if confirmed) or null (if dismissed)

// when you're here textTypedIntoPrompt contains the input
// and your browser already forgot it came from a prompt

var theMessage =                                       
// then you create a variable named theMessage
                 "You typed : " + textTypedIntoPrompt; 
// and you assign to it the string 'you typed : ' followed by the value of textTypedIntoPrompt
// (which is the return value of prompt) 

console.log(theMessage);
// finally you print this string into the console 
// use ctrl+shift+k to open the console in most browsers
```

---

and finally a snippet proving `console.log` doesn't open a prompt

```js
console.log("didn't open a prompt :)")
```

while this one proves `prompt` does open a prompt (as it's name is telling us)

```js
prompt("I opened a prompt", "you can also set a default value")
// the return value is not saved into a variable so it is lost
```

Comment: Thanks jonatjano.

1. Please why does yours have console.log(1) at the top.

2. My question really is, why does console.log(theMessage); jump to the other declaration with the prompt in it first? (since textTypedIntoPrompt isn't what is being printed).

Comment: @Richfella happy to help, don't forget to mark the response as accepted to make it clear to future visitors ;)

Comment: Didn't know "enter" submits posts.

Please I've just added some questions to my reply above. Regards

Comment: the `console.log(1)` was a mistake, I already removed it, reaload the page if it is still shown. For the other question, I'll update the answer with more details

Comment: @Richfella modified ;)